# Retrieve collection made up from SQL LIKE operator using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a search form on my website; when the user inputs a search term this is passed into the URL Query string. I am wanting to use this data to build a collection using the SQL LIKE operator.

I have set up a 'Product' controller with a search method.

```
public function search()
{

    $searchTerm = request('s');

    $products  = Product::where('productTitle', 'LIKE', '%{{$searchTerm}}%');

    return $products;

    return view('search', [
        'searchTerm' => $searchTerm,
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

However, when I run this, I receive the following error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you don't need the `{{ }}` within the string, just do the following:

```
$products  = Product::where('productTitle', 'LIKE', "%$searchTerm%")->get();
```

Notice the `->get()` at the end is what returns the collection.

Comment: is that what I gave you above to run? You have to use `""` double quotes in order the value of `$searchTerm` to become what it holds.

`'%$searchTerm%'` will equal to `"%$searchTerm%"`, while `"%$searchTerm%" ` will equal to `"%querystring%"`. So to evaluate a variable within quotes you have to use double quotes instead of single, I hope I am clear.

Comment: @MichaelBarley you can try debugging what do you get back from your `$searchTerm` using `dd($searchTerm)`.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
public function search()
{

    $searchTerm = request('s');

    $data['products']  = Product::where('productTitle', 'LIKE', '%$searchTerm%')->get();

        return view('search',$data);
}
```

thi is return the data on your view. then on your view you initiate `@foreach @endforeach` to display the result like:

```
@extends('app.layout')

@section('content')

  @foreach( $products as $p)

    {{ $p->searchTerm }}
    {{ $p->products }}

  @endforeach

@endsection
```

Comment: You just made a query but didn't trigger it. Use get() function at the end.

Comment: there is get() function. go back and check at the code once again